# How To Model Ornamental Grass Procedurally

Tags: modeling, particles, physics, hair, procedural

I am trying to model an ornamental grass procedurally (Miscanthus sinensis 'Gracillimus'). I want to be able to do this procedurally (not combing for example) because, unlike normal grass, it has a lot of strands with a specific form and I still want to be able to adjust it quickly to make variations or similar plants.

As shown in the screenshot, I tried using hair dynamics, which approaches the result I want. But despite that I just can't get it right using this method.

My knowledge of hair dynamics and physics isn't yet adequate enough. Maybe someone knows the best practices to accomplish the creation of this plant?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure reading your question about what could be good or bad in the hair model? Is that kind of thing you are looking for? https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqFnD.jpg

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes indeed, the outer ones of your image are the thing I'm looking for. In my model the strands flare out almost inmediatally which prevents the right form. Meanwhile I'm making progress and it is going the right way. I wasn't using the Pin Goal Strength which was the main reason it did not work well. But I can still use the help. How did you do it?

Comment: I've used keyed (see in physics) particles (not hair but emitter) with path rendering. The idea is to propagate the particles from a shape to another (in the image I've upload 3 shapes per plant). So particles will start at the first then go to the 2nd and finally reach the third. As each step is "the mesh you want" you can control nearly all rapidly.

Comment: Seems like a good method. You mean like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgmJsLcLXUI but then with path rendering?

Comment: Yes, same principal but with path. The one I did in the image is based on a disk for the first, an half sphere for the second and a half sphere opened at the top for the third. From that, just move them, rotate, scale, deform them as you want to make variations.

Comment: Great! I have to do some research because I've never used particle emitters before, could you point me in the good direction with an excisting tutorial or some explanation?

Comment: I would recommend something like Blender Guru's Fur tutorial. It covers most of the hair settings, and it might work well for your grass: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVj1fETtuN8

Comment: @Lemon, it would be great if you could make an answer to explain in detail, thanks!  ;)

Comment: @moonboots, was thinking about it. but this one should be a long one and not compatible with other things for the moment. If you have time, feel free to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6316/ (2.8, bad lines are due to a bug I think... reenter edit mode for each key object to make it disappear). Also I wanted to find a good and short way to go to curves (model on the left and right) but for now nothing very good I think.

Comment: ok, if you ever have time then  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the upload, I will look into it when I have the time. I think I now know how to make it work with hair particles also. When I have had the time to make it work I will post it as an answer. @Lemon if you have the time to post an detailed answer it would be very welcome. I don't want to rush you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will look into it.

Comment: @Vince, FYI, made few other tests in between and path orders are hard to manage between key objects. I'll try to see why, but if you have a good solution keep it and don't waste too much time on mine (I'll work on it... later... can't now)

Comment: @lemon, I see, I will work on it when I find the time. No problem, I appreciate the help.